# App sandbox not enabled

Tags: macos

I have my own executable file which is named as "testQueue" and bundled with my main app(testApp) to achieve my requirements. 
testQueue is a executable file written in C .

I sandboxed this executable using below options and added in the app :

- Code signing : Mac developer 3rd party application
- Enabled com.apple.security.app-sandbox = TRUE in testQueue.entitlements
- Enabled com.apple.security.inherit = TRUE in testQueue.entitlements

Still i received the following error from apple review team.

```
"App sandbox not enabled - The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list. Refer to the App Sandbox page for more information on sandboxing your app.

testApp.app/Contents/Resources/testQueue"
```

i would like to know if anything else needs to be added in project settings?

Comment: It looks like you aren't correctly setting the entitlements for this bundled executable.

Comment: Actually for that bundled executable, we have that source code(C code)   . if we open that source code in xcode, we dont have option for enabling entitlement. so we added productname.entitlements manually  in xcode and we build that as executable. then we bundled this executable with our apps. Is there any changes in setting the entitlements for this bundled executable?

Comment: this blog says it all - http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/ but in brief any sub-packages must be signed/entitled to work on MAS deploys

Comment: I have run in the same issue how to solve it ?
can you please share how did u managed to submit it ?

Comment: NO i haven't resolved this issue. I moved to packagemaker to pack my apps and third party executables as a single .pkg file.

Answer (score 32):

Go to your target -> Capabilities -> put App Sandbox in ON.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was useful

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Sorted out my application.

Comment: I am getting the similar error in command line tool, however, there is no such capabilities tab in the project. So what I did I passes the entitlement plist in the codesign command. Still, I am getting this error.

Comment: @Khushneet same issue i am also facing  did u resolved? if yes how?

Comment: As far as I remember, I code-signed my app bundle with 'com.apple.security.app-sandbox' entitlements and the command line tool with 'com.apple.security.inherit' entitlement.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW15

Please let me know what exact issue you are facing right now as I forgot mine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Xamarin check the "Enable App Sandbox" option on your "Entitlements" file
[image]

Then on the "Mac Signing" options:

- Choose a custom entitlements file
- Enable the option "Sign the installer packer"

Before archiving the file for publishing

[image]

Comment: Xamarin/Microsoft please update your documentation! This took me so long to find

Answer (score 0):

Should be done here, apparently the place changed :
[image]